# Round up to 5 cents

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, floor, ceil

I have got the next query.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Test] (@i DECIMAL(10, 2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @j DECIMAL(10, 2)

    SET @j = @i - floor(@i)

    RETURN CASE 
            WHEN @j < 0.25
                THEN floor(@i)
            WHEN @j < 0.75
                THEN floor(@i) + 0.5
            ELSE ceiling(@i)
            END
END

return case when @j<0.25 then floor(@i) when @j<0.75 then floor(@i)+0.5 else ceiling(@i) end

END
```

This is for round with 0.5, but how can I change this to always round up with 0.05, unless it's already at an round of 0.05?

Comment: Multiply by 20, round to integer (or add 0.5 and truncate to integer), divide by 20.

Comment: Multiply by 20, use CEILING to round up to the nearest 0.05 fraction, divide by 20.

Comment: Your query is not technically correct, have you executed the procedure with the return statement? Can you edit the question and update with the right executable query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ceiling()` function:

```
ceiling(@i / 0.05) * 0.05
```

This seems much simpler than what you are trying to do.